# preg_replace wont create links

Tags: php

Hi i am having a big problem with this function called post_link($str)

```
<?php        
function post_link($str)
{
    if(preg_match("#(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?#",$str,$url)){

    return preg_replace("#(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?#","<a href='$0'>$0</a>",$str);
    } 
    else
    {
        return $str;
    }
}      

?>
```

it won't create links as I would like it to?

this is what it does at the moment when i want to create a link to this link:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8
```

the result is this

```
href='http://youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8'>youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8
```

what could be causing this to happen please help. why the href attribute appears.

Comment: i tested this with your input string and don't get the same result as you posted.

Comment: Your regular expression will never match `youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8`, since it specifies that the string has to begin with either http, https, ftp or ftps. This site changed my life when I started working with regular expressions : http://www.regexper.com

Comment: the original input was suppose to be http://www
.youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8 but i could not post my question until i removed http://www from my question. can check with that as an input?

Answer (score 0):

First,  it's not usefull to test if the string match your pattern before replacing... preg replace doesn't replace if your string doesn't match.

This is enough:

```
function post_link ($str){
    return preg_replace("...", $str)
}
```

And it will be easier to debug.

Then, here is my test :

```
[ ~]$ cat script.php 
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo preg_replace("#(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?#","<a href='$0'>$0</a>", $argv[1]) . "\n";
?>
[ ~]$ ./script.php "http://youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8"
<a href='http://youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8'>http://youtube.com/watch?v=4EvNxWhskf8</a>
[ ~]$
```

It's seems the result expected, isn't it ? So, you must debug more (inspect your variables with a debugger such as xdebug for example). Otherwise, you should give us more details about your code, your output, ...

Moreover, I note that your example of link doesn't include the protocol (`http://` for example). If it's a real example, your regex never match this string...

Answer (score 0):

RegExp matches are divided by subpatterns defined with `()` in pattern. So for every subpattern in your pattern, you will get a partial match. The first match in set is whole match, second is for first `(expr)` ... etc. So $0 = full matched string. $1 = 'http' or 'https' or 'ftp' or 'ftps', $2 = '(/\S*)'.

So, you need to put proper part of expression into `()`, and give a right number in replacement string.